# Spring JUnit Test

Tags: java, spring, junit

I like to test my spring code:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/applicationContext.xml" })
@Transactional()
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    MyDao dao;

    @org.junit.Test
    @Rollback(false)
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {
        MyEntity e = new MyEntity();
        dao.create(e);
    }
}
```

Running this test with eclipse (as an JUNIT test) just gives an Nullpointer-Exception.

What have I done wrong? Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` to your class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/applicationContext.xml" })
@Transactional()
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    MyDao dao;

    @org.junit.Test
    @Rollback(false)
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {
        MyEntity e = new MyEntity();
        dao.create(e);
    }
}
```

You need `spring-test` for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a Transactional test base class like this

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:applicationContext.xml")
public class IntegrateTestBase extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
}
```

Then wirite your test class

```
public class Test extends IntegrateTestBase {

    @Autowired
    MyDao dao;

    @org.junit.Test
    @Rollback(false)
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {
        MyEntity e = new MyEntity();
        dao.create(e);
    }
}
```

You need not write `@ContextConfiguration` and `@Transcational` in each test class